# WMS Bad request in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have used OpenLayers2 in order to show a layer with points from Geoserver.
I try now to transform the code from Openlayers2 to OpenLayers3 but I am facing some issues. 
I have walked through this nice tutorial: [OpenLayers3](http://christopherjennison.com/openlayers-3-beginners-part-2/)
and I have a good understanding of how to add layers from localhost geoserver in OL2.

This is part of my code:

```
function init() {

map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:900913',
        center:[0,0],
        zoom:5
    })
});

var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

map.addLayer(newLayer);

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        preload: Infinity,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
        serverType:'geoserver',
        params:{
            'LAYERS':"dSpatialAnalysis:categoriesdata", 'TILED':true
        }
    })
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
}
```

For some reason I get a:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&R…TYLES=&BBOX=2504688.542848654%2C0%2C3757032.814272982%2C1252344.2714243277 400 (Bad Request)
```

I understand that somethings regarding the projections have changed in OL3 and I wonder if this is related with the errors I get. 
I also checked if the layer works correctly. I can view it in the "Layer Preview" of geoserver and it works fine with OpenLayers2. 
What can it be the issue?

Comment: try not using the gwc maybe for testing

Comment: I also tried this. I get the same error.

Comment: Copy the whole request from the Bad Request line and send that with a browser. Does it give the same error?

Comment: When I include the gwc I get: "400: Unable to parse layers parameter from request." When I don't include it I get: "The requested resource () is not available."

Comment: change your url from this `url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms'` to this `url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'`

Comment: @Pavlo, thanks man. That was it! No idea why this cause an error in OL3 and not it OL2. If you make it an official answer I will accept it.

Comment: no probs amigo. glad to help. no need for amenities your thanks is enough

Comment: @pavlos classy.